# ReSharper adds an unexpected NotNull attribute to a method parameter in ArrayList

Tags: c#, resharper

When using `System.Collections.ArrayList` one can add null instances to the list. This is clear from the documentation:

[image]

Now, if I enable ReSharper (Ultimate, v10.0.2), I get the following change to the method signature in Visual Studio:

[image]

So ReSharper seems to be adding metadata to the method indicating that it doesn't support nulls when the documentation clearly states that it does.

I assume that the idea is to warn against adding nulls to an `ArrayList`, and that might make sense (although I'm not sure about that, since it's explicitly allowed in the documentation.)

However, a problem arises if I define a subclass like this:

```
public class ArrayListEx : ArrayList
{
    public override int Add(object value)
    {
        if (value != null)
            return base.Add(value);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

ReSharper will now give a potentially dangerous warning:

[image]

Here, one might wrongly assume that the statement `value != null` can be replaced with `true`. But the method can be called with nothing but a ReSharper warning, not with a compilation or runtime error. Since that warning might be ignored, the statement that it *can't* be null is false.

So, given that I've analysed this correctly, my questions are:

- Is it acceptable that ReSharper adds this metadata to the parameter at all (when it's not in line with the documentation)?
- Shouldn't the side effect, where ReSharper claims that an expression will always be true, where that's not necessarily the case, be considered a serious bug?

Comment: Indeed, `myArrList.Add(null)` runs and compiles but throws a Resharper-Warning: `Possible null assignement to entity marked with NotNull-attribute`. Seems odd to mee too

Comment: I would definitely report this to them as a bug.

Comment: Anyway: why use `ArrayList` at all, go with time and use generic equivalent `List<T>`. Warning does not occur there. However I agree on reporting it as a bug.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: Indeed. I noticed this in legacy code that's using the non-generic version.

Comment: Really? Oh no, than I fear the point when our company offially uses ReSharper as we also have much legacy-code of this kind.

Comment: I've filed a bug report.

Comment: @steinar there [already was one](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-430170), fwiw. Yours is better :)

Comment: Putting null into a collection is always a potential risk. You can suppress the warning for one line with  // ReSharper disable once AssignNullToNotNullAttribute, which documents that you are aware of the risk and truly WANT to deposit a booby trap in your ArrayList.